# What are the risks of using a hotspot application in my laptop?

Tags: laptop

I downloaded hotspot application on my laptop, and all my friends using data through. Might my laptop have any problem with it?

Comment: Depends what you mean by problem, express your concerns with more detail

Comment: No, but you might if they do something illegal ...

Answer (score -1):

Nothing wrong with it. Make hotspot on your laptop is always a best idea to share your Internet with other devices, mobile and laptoos, and use it forever.

Share your package with your friends. Hotspot and some others like Connectify are available for best performance.